# Rails | Add Action Button (delete,edit etc) on Datatables Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

How can I add delete and edit button column using the json/ajax approach?

```
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/edit.png'), editcontent_path(page), :title => "edit" %>
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/delete.png'), page, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, :title => "delete"  %>
```

i want to input on datatables/page_datatables.rb

```
class PagesDatatable
  delegate :params, :truncate, :html_safe, :link_to, to: :@view

  .....

  def data
    pages.map do |page|
      [
          page.name
          page.permalink,
          truncate(page.content, :length => 160).html_safe
          #####  I want to input here ####

      ]
    end
  end

  ......
  ......

end
```

please help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's work for me,

```
class PagesDatatable
delegate :params, :truncate, :html_safe, :link_to, :edit_page_path, :page, to: :@view

    .....

    .....

    def data
        pages.map do |page|
          [
              page.name,
              page.permalink,
              truncate(page.content, :length => 160).html_safe,
              link_to("edit", edit_page_path(page)),
              link_to("delete", page, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }) 

          ]
        end
      end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your routes. However, you may get lights from the following example:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/edit.png'), [:edit, page], :title => "edit" %>
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/delete.png'), page, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :title => "delete"  %>
```

Comment: how do I properly link to an edit path end delete in PagesDatatable? It gives me a no method error if I do link_to("edit", edit_page_path(page))